# While uploading data to my local database i am getting an error called "Object must implement convertible"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, local-database

When i am trying to upload a file to my local database I am getting an error called "Object must implement |Convertible"

I really don't have idea why its saying like that. I need help please.

Error image:

[image]

Error removing try and catch- https://imageshack.com/i/kpgFCzkrp

Code I am trying:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Throw error if attachment cell is not selected.
            //make sure user select only single cell
            if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                UploadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0]);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Select a single cell from Attachment column", "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

private void UploadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            //Set File dialog properties
            fileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
            fileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
            fileDialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
            fileDialog.Title = "Select a file";
            fileDialog.Multiselect = true;

            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CncConnectionString);
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileDialog.FileName);
                byte[] binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileDialog.FileName);
                cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = fileInfo.Name;
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO CncInfo (Drawings) VALUES (@DATA)", cnn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", binaryData);

                cnn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

When i updated the catch with below codes. i got the error like this https://imageshack.com/i/ip6ESuuhp

```
   catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

`

Comment: That's IConvertible.  Interfaces conventionally start with "I".  Try commenting out your try - catch blocks.  That way you'll see the full stack trace of the error, which will tell you where the error is coming from in your code. Or print out ex.StackTrace.

Comment: @kristianp i really appreciate that if you could edit it and tell me. Because i am really new to this field

Comment: Can you change ex.Message in your code to ex.StackTrace and put the result in your question please?  That is easy to do.

Comment: @kristianp Ok i updated the error as per you said.. Please let me know

Comment: It looks like you need to set the type of the parameter, e.g.  something like cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", binaryData, SqlType.Blob);

Comment: Oh my drawing field type is: nvarchar..https://imageshack.com/i/ewaOkInap

Comment: But the problem is when i make the field to the binarydata. And when i drag the grid to the form. Then i am getting "X" symbol which mean i am getting to =o much of error. https://imageshack.com/i/exI0zCxlp

Comment: And if i add `cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", binaryData, SqlType.Blob);`. These lines instead of `cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", binaryData, SqlType.Blob); ` its telling Error : The name 'SqlType' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Ah, it should be SqlDbType.VarBinary.

Comment: i made to `cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", SqlDbType.VarBinary);` so i am getting a error like this <https://imageshack.com/i/ewQGgFG2j>

Answer (score 0):

The [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyfxw8k7.aspx) method is deprecated precisely because it does not work in a way you expect it to. Do what the warning message tells you to and use [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx).